# Out of universe, what makes the TARDIS noise?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, sound-effects

The noise made by the TARDIS in *Doctor Who* has been the same ever since its very first trip way back in 1963:

In-universe, it's the wheezing of the time rotor, possibly because of the Doctor leaving the handbrake on. But **what makes this sound effect out-of-universe?** Whatever it is, it's been producing pretty much the same sound for the last 50+ years.

Comment: http://www.themindrobber.co.uk/tardis-sound-effects-materialisation.html

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/tvandradio/doctor-who/10469811/The-secrets-behind-the-sounds-of-Doctor-Who.html

Comment: @Valorum y u comment and no answer? :-)

Comment: Nah, this is basically google-fodder.

Comment: @Valorum So is almost anything, if you have enough google-fu.

Comment: True, but this was especially easy to answer. So much so that I almost downvoted since *any* level of research would have instantly proffered the answer.

Comment: @Valorum - I saw a Matrix question that looked like Google-fodder recently. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### At least originally, keys scraped on a piano

[According to the person](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-norfolk-25051061) who made it:

> On how the Tardis should sound, he said: "I don't know who thought of
>   it, but we came up with the 'rending of the fabric of time and space'.
>   I was in a cinema and in the interval I had a programme and I drew it
>   - exactly how I wanted it to go together.
>
> "I'd done a programme called The Survivors where we had to have the
>   sound of a ship scraping on the rocks, and the piano sounds I'd used
>   for that, very slowed down, seemed a good starting point.
>
> Mr Hodgson used a device known as a ring modulator to create the sound
>   of the Daleks
>
> "I got my bunch of keys out, I got my mum's front door key and scraped
>   that up the strings. We did that several times on the bass strings on
>   an old Sunday school piano that had been taken apart. "So we took
>   those and speeded them up, slowed them down and cut several of them
>   together and started to add feedback to get that echoey sort of
>   thing."

The takeoff sound specifically:

> "They came to listen to it and said they liked it, but there was
>   something missing - why hadn't I put a rising note in it? "I said
>   'time machines don't go up, they go everywhere'. They said 'well we
>   think it needs it'. So I put the rising note in it with loads of
>   feedback and the Tardis was born.

The landing sound was the same as the takeoff sound, but with a "bang"  at the end!

> "Unfortunately, I'd spent so much time on the sound of it taking off,
>   when we were asked for it to land I only had three days to sort that
>   out. So I literally played it backwards, again with loads of feedback
>   on it, and put a great big bang on the end of it."

Comment: Quite similar to the [creation of Godzilla's roar](http://www.npr.org/2014/05/18/312839612/whats-in-a-roar-crafting-godzillas-iconic-sound)!